# python QLineEdit Text Color

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I am trying to create a demonstration app to show how to change font colors.

I can do it in QLabel and QTextEdit

I have found no way to change the foreground text color for a QLineEdit.

The only thing I've tried that does not throw an error is:

```
color = QColorDialog.getColor(defaultHost.textColor(), pWidget, 'Get Text Color')
myPalette.setColor(myPalette.WindowText, QColor(color))
```

But, the text color remains black...

Is it or is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 26):

You can do it by [setting the object's style sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html):

```
self.my_line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()

self.my_line_edit.setStyleSheet("color: red;")

# or

self.my_line_edit.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")

# or

self.my_line_edit.setStyleSheet("""
    QLabel {
        color: red;
    }
    """)
```

Answer (score 8):

I solved for font text and background

```
 self.my_line_edit.setStyleSheet(
                """QLineEdit { background-color: green; color: white }""")
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is a code snippet that took me two days of trial and error to figure out. I hope it helps other newbies like myself. My comments in the code should help, too.

```
def set_palette(pWidget, pItem):
    # Get the pallet
    myPalette = pWidget.palette()
    defaultHost = led_dem.textEdit

    if isinstance(pWidget, QPushButton):
        # NOTE: Using stylesheets will temporarily change the color dialog popups push buttons
        print "Instance Is: %s " %(pWidget.objectName())
        # Existing colors.
        bgColor = pWidget.palette().color(QPalette.Background)
        fgColor = pWidget.palette().color(QPalette.Foreground)
        # Convert the QColors to a string hex for use in the Stylesheet.
        bg = bgColor.name()
        fg = fgColor.name()

        if pItem == 'Text':
            # Use the color dialog with a dummy widget to obtain a new QColor for the parameter we are changing.
            color = QColorDialog.getColor(defaultHost.textColor(), pWidget, 'Get Text Color')
            # Convert it to a string HEX
            fg = color.name()
            # Update all parameters of interest
            pWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color: ' + bg + ';color: ' + fg)

        if pItem == 'Background':
            color = QColorDialog.getColor(defaultHost.textColor(), pWidget, 'Get Background Color')
            myPalette.setColor(myPalette.Base, QColor(color))
            bg = color.name()
            pWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color: ' + bg + ';color: ' + fg)
```

This snippet shows:

- how to find what type of widget you are dealing with;
- how to covert a `QColor` from a `QColorDialog` into a string HEX format for use with a stylesheet; and
- how to use the `QColorDialog` when the widget doesn't use a palette element of the type you need.

In my case I am using `defaultHost = led_dem.textEdit` where `led_dem` is my form and `textEdit` is a `textEdit` on the form.

Also, `pWidget` is the complete widget definition including `form` and `instance`.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you spent all that time on this answer, when you'd already been given a one-line solution to your original question. But I suspect that your continuing difficulties on this subject stem from a failure to understand what the various [color roles](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) do - in particular, `Background` and `Foreground` (which are both obsolete) aren't used in the way that you think they are (you should be using `Base` and `Text`, instead).

Comment: "A Failure To Understand" You are right on target. I have found QT to be a somewhat confusing 'discipline'. And, there is no one where I am at that uses it at the level I do. I spent the time on the answer because by the time I got a response on here, I had (mostly) figured it out the hard way.

Comment: Could not get 'Base' and 'Text' to work on a QPushbutton using Python 2.7.x and QT 4.8.5

Comment: Why would you think that `Base` and `Text` would work with a `QPushButton`? Your question is about changing the font colours in a `QLineEdit`. Please take the time to read the documentation for color roles that I linked to in my previous comment - the accompanying illustration could hardly make it clearer what roles you should be using for buttons.

Comment: My apologies: I asked a question about a QLineEdit, and provided code for a QPushbutton.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I do it not using css

```
Palette= QtGui.QPalette()
Palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtCore.Qt.red)
self.lineEdit.setPalette(Palette)
```

QLineEdit has a method **initStyleOption** and initStyleOption inherits QStyleOption, and then QStyleOption has a Method QPalette. Now you can take advatage of using QPalette methods.

you can visit this link for reference http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked first try:
`self.LBLDefteraStatusState.setStyleSheet('color: green;')`